# Python: Recursively group operands together with their operators in a list

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, operators, formula

I have a list that contains symbols and operators, like this:

```
[['B31', '+', 'W311', '*', ['B21', '+', 'W211', '*', ['B11', '+', 'W111', '*', 'x'], '+', 'W221', '*',
                                       ['B12', '+', 'W121', '*', 'x']], '+', 'W312', '*',
             ['B22', '+', 'W212', '*', ['B11', '+', 'W111', '*', 'x'], '+', 'W222', '*',
              ['B12', '+', 'W121', '*', 'x']]]]
```

I wish to group operators together with their operands in lists of 3 elements, here that would be

```
[['B31', '+',
          ['W311', '*',
           ['B21', '+',
            [['W211', '*', [['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']]],
             '+', ['W221', '*',
                   ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]]]]],
         '+', ['W312', '*',
               ['B22', '+',
                [['W212', '*', ['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']]],
                 '+', ['W222', '*',
                       ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]]]]]
```

My algorithm looks like this:

```
def group_by_symbol(formula: Union[List, str], symbol: str) -> List:
"""
Group multiplication in formula: a op b -> [a op b]
:param formula: contains operations not inside a list.
:return: operations enclosed in a list.
"""
modified_formula = formula

# loop backwards
for i in range(len(modified_formula) - 1, -1, -1):
    if i > len(modified_formula) - 1:
        continue

    if modified_formula[i] == symbol:
        # introduce parentheses around symbol
        group = [modified_formula[i - 1], modified_formula[i], modified_formula[i + 1]]
        del modified_formula[i:i + 2]
        modified_formula[i - 1] = group
    elif isinstance(modified_formula[i], List) \
            and len(modified_formula[i]) > 3:
        # recurse
        modified_formula[i] = group_by_symbol(modified_formula[i], symbol)

return modified_formula
```

It is called like below:

```
grouped = group_by_symbol(formula, '*')
grouped = group_by_symbol(grouped, '+')
```

However, the case where there is more than one addition in the same list does not create the desired groups and the result I obtain is the following, where there occurs more than one + symbol in a list, and not all lists have a size of 3:

```
[[['B31', '+', [['W311', '*', ['B21', '+', ['W211', '*', ['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']]], '+',
                                               ['W221', '*', ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]],
                                '+', ['W312', '*',
                                      ['B22', '+', ['W212', '*', ['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']]], '+',
                                       ['W222', '*', ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]]]]]]
```

I suspect the error has something to do with an early exit from recursion, however, checking the sublist to contain only strings in the condition results in an endless recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can dramatically simplify the program by writing a pure function. The numbered comments here correspond to the the source code numbers in the program below.

1. If there is no operation, `op`, we have reached the base case. If the supplied argument, `arg`, is a list, convert it to an expression or simply return the `arg`.
2. By induction, there *is* an operation, `op`. If the supplied `arg` is a list, we need to recursively convert it, too. Return a 3-part expression with `expr(*arg)`, the `op`, and the recursive result, `expr(*more)`
3. By induction, there is an operation and the supplied `arg` is *not* a list. Return a 3-part expression with `arg`, the `op`, and the recursive result, `expr(*more)`

```py
tree = \
  [['B31','+','W311','*',['B21','+','W211','*',['B11','+','W111','*','x'],'+','W221','*',['B12','+','W121','*','x']],'+','W312','*',['B22','+','W212','*',['B11','+','W111','*','x'],'+','W222','*',['B12','+','W121','*','x']]]]

def expr(arg, op = None, *more):
  if not op:
    return expr(*arg) if isinstance(arg, list) else arg #1
  elif isinstance(arg, list):
    return [ expr(*arg), op, expr(*more) ]              #2
  else:
    return [ arg, op, expr(*more) ]                     #3


print(expr(tree))
# ['B31', '+', ['W311', '*', [['B21', '+', ['W211', '*', [['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']], '+', ['W221', '*', ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]]], '+', ['W312', '*', ['B22', '+', ['W212', '*', [['B11', '+', ['W111', '*', 'x']], '+', ['W222', '*', ['B12', '+', ['W121', '*', 'x']]]]]]]]]]
```

Maybe we can verify the output a little better if we convert the expression to a string -

```py
def expr_to_str(expr1, op, expr2):
  return \
  f"({expr_to_str(*expr1) if isinstance(expr1, list) else expr1} {op} {expr_to_str(*expr2) if isinstance(expr2, list) else expr2})"

print(expr_to_str(*expr(tree)))
# (B31 + (W311 * ((B21 + (W211 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W221 * (B12 + (W121 * x)))))) + (W312 * (B22 + (W212 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W222 * (B12 + (W121 * x))))))))))
```

Here's another way using a `class` -

```py
class expr:
  def __init__(self, x, op = None, *y):
    self.op = op
    self.x = expr(*x) if isinstance(x, list) else x
    self.y = expr(*y) if y else y

  def __str__(self):
    if not self.op:
      return f"{self.x}"
    else:
      return f"({self.x} {self.op} {self.y})"

print(expr(tree))
# (B31 + (W311 * ((B21 + (W211 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W221 * (B12 + (W121 * x)))))) + (W312 * (B22 + (W212 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W222 * (B12 + (W121 * x))))))))))
```

---

**varaidic support**

In a comment you ask if the `expr` can support 3-element results *and* 2-element results. Here is one such flexible implementation -

In the constructor, `__init__`, we do a simple case analysis -

1. If the input `a` is a list and the list is less than `4` elements, we don't need to break anything down. Simply map `expr` over each element of `a`.
2. By induction, the input `a` is a list *at least* 4 elements, so we need to break it into smaller expressions. Construct an expression of the first element, `expr(a[0])`, the second element, `expr(a[1])`, and the recursive result of all remaining elements, `expr(a[2::])`
3. By induction, the input `a` is *not* a list, ie it is a *single* item. Set the expression's data to the singleton, `[ a ]`

In the `__str__` method, we do a similar analysis to convert our expression's `data` into a string -

1. When `self.data` is empty, return the empty string, `""`
2. By induction, `self.data` is *not* empty. If it is less than 2 elements (singleton), return the singleton result, `f"{self.data[0]}"`
3. By induction, `self.data` is *at least* 2 or more elements. return a `(...)`-enclosed string where each part is recursively converted to a `str` and joined with a space, `" "`

```py
class expr:
  def __init__(self, a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
      if len(a) < 4:
        self.data = [ expr(x) for x in a ]                   #1
      else:
        self.data = [ expr(a[0]), expr(a[1]), expr(a[2::]) ] #2
    else:
      self.data = [ a ]                                      #3

  def __str__(self):
    if not self.data:
      return ""                                              #1 empty
    elif len(self.data) < 2:
      return f"{self.data[0]}"                               #2 singleton
    else:
      return "(" + " ".join(str(x) for x in self.data) + ")" #3 variadic

print(expr(tree))
# (B31 + (W311 * ((B21 + (W211 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W221 * (B12 + (W121 * x)))))) + (W312 * (B22 + (W212 * ((B11 + (W111 * x)) + (W222 * (B12 + (W121 * x))))))))))

print(expr([[ "¬", ["a", "+", "b"]], "and", [["length", "x"], ">", 0]]))
# ((¬ (a + b)) and ((length x) > 0))
```

---

**breaking it down**

By decomposing a complex problem into smaller parts, it easier to solve the sub-problems and it affords us more flexibility and control. For what it's worth, this technique does not rely on Python's specific OOP mechanisms. These are ordinary, well-defined, pure functions -

```py
def unit(): return ('unit',)
def nullary(op): return ('nullary', op)
def unary(op, a): return ('unary', op, a)
def binary(op, a, b): return ('binary', op, a, b)
```

Now using a flat case analysis as we've done before, we implement our recursive expression constructor `expr`  -

1. if the input `a` is not a list, it is a single value. construct a `nullary` expression with `a`
2. By induction, the input *is* a list. If the list is empty, construct an empty result, the `unit` expression.
3. By induction, the input *not* an empty list. If it contains exactly one element, construct a `nullary` expression with the only element, `expr(a[0])`
4. By induction, the input contains *at least* two elements. If the input is exactly two elements, construct a `unary` expression with `expr(a[0])` and `expr(a[1])`
5. By induction, the input contains *at least* three elements. If the input operator `is_infix` position, convert to prefix position. Construct a `binary` expression with `expr(a[0])` and `expr(a[1])` in swapped position, and the recursive result `expr(a[2::])`
6. By induction, the input contains at least three elements as is *not* in infix position. Construct an ordinary (prefix position) `binary` expression of `expr(a[0])` and `expr(a[1])` and the recursive result `expr(a[2::])`

```py
infix_ops = set([ '+', '-', '*', '/', '>', '<', 'and', 'or' ])

def is_infix (a):
  return a[1] in infix_ops

def expr(a):
  if not isinstance(a, list):
    return nullary(a)                                    #1
  elif len(a) == 0:
      return unit()                                      #2
  elif len(a) == 1:
    return nullary(expr(a[0]))                           #3
  elif len(a) == 2:
    return unary(expr(a[0]), expr(a[1]))                 #4
  elif is_infix(a):
    return binary(expr(a[1]), expr(a[0]), expr(a[2::]))  #5
  else:
    return binary(expr(a[0]), expr(a[1]), expr(a[2::]))  #6
```

Now to see the result -

```py
tree2 = \
  [[ "¬", ["a", "+", "b"]], "and", [["length", "x"], ">", 0]]

print(expr(tree2))
# ('binary', ('nullary', 'and'), ('unary', ('nullary', '¬'), ('binary', ('nullary', '+'), ('nullary', 'a'), ('nullary', ('nullary', 'b')))), ('nullary', ('binary', ('nullary', '>'), ('unary', ('nullary', 'length'), ('nullary', 'x')), ('nullary', ('nullary', 0)))))
```

This is just *one possible* representation of our expressions. Because we implemented our expressions using `tuple`, Python is able to print them out, despite being verbose. By contrast, here's how Python chooses to represent objects -

```py
class foo: pass
f = foo()
print(f)
# <__main__.foo object at 0x7f2ba03bc8e0>
```

What's important here is that our expression data structure is *well-defined* and we can easily perform computations on it or represent it other ways -

```py
def expr_to_str(m):
  if not isinstance(m, tuple):
    return str(m)
  elif m[0] == "unit":
    return ""
  elif m[0] == "nullary":
    return expr_to_str(m[1])
  elif m[0] == "unary":
    return f"({expr_to_str(m[1])} {expr_to_str(m[2])})"
  elif m[0] == "binary":
    return f"({expr_to_str(m[1])} {expr_to_str(m[2])} {expr_to_str(m[3])})"
  else:
    raise TypeError("invalid expression type", m[0])

print(expr_to_str(expr(tree2)))
# (and (¬ (+ a b)) (> (length x) 0))
```

---

**evaluating an expression**

So what if we wanted to *evaluate* one of our expressions?

```py
m = expr([3, "+", 2, "*", 5, "-", 1])

print(expr_to_str(m))
# (+ 3 (* 2 (- 5 1)))

print(eval_expr(m))
# 11
```

You're just a few steps away from being able to write `eval_expr` -

```py
def eval_expr(m):
  if not isinstance(m, tuple):
      return m
  elif m[0] == "unit":
    return None
  elif m[0] == "nullary":
    return eval0(m[1])
  elif m[0] == "unary":
    return eval1(m[1], m[2])
  elif m[0] == "binary":
    return eval2(m[1], m[2], m[3])
  else:
    raise TypeError("invalid expression type", m[0])
```

See, complex problems are easier when breaking them down into small parts. Now we just write `eval0`, `eval1`, and `eval2` -

```py
def eval0(op):
  return eval_expr(op)

def eval1(op, a):
  if op == expr("not"):      # or op == expr("¬") ...
    return not eval_expr(a)
  elif op == expr("neg"):    # or op == expr("~") ...
    return -eval_expr(a)
  # +, ++, --, etc...
  else:
    raise ValueError("invalid op", op)

def eval2(op, a, b):
  if op == expr("+"):
      return eval_expr(a) + eval_expr(b)
  elif op == expr("-"):
    return eval_expr(a) - eval_expr(b)
  elif op == expr("*"):
    return eval_expr(a) * eval_expr(b)
  elif op == expr("/"):
    return eval_expr(a) / eval_expr(b)
  elif op == expr("and"):
    return eval_expr(a) and eval_expr(b)
  # >, <, or, xor, etc...
  else:
    raise ValueError("invalid op", op)
```

Let's see a mixture of expressions now -

```py
print(eval_expr(expr([True, 'and', ['not', False]])))
# True

print(eval_expr(expr(['neg', [9, '*', 11]])))
# -99

print(eval_expr(expr(['stay', '+', 'inside'])))
# 'stayinside'
```

You can even define your own functions -

```py
def eval1(op, a):
  # ...
  elif op == expr('scream'):
    return eval_expr(a).upper() # make uppercase!
  else:
    raise ValueError("invalid op", op)
```

And use them in your expressions -

```py
print(eval_expr(expr(["scream", ["stay", "+", "inside"]])))
# 'STAYINSIDE'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, great answer. I figured I could solve this by using some kind of OO mechanism, but didn't quite get behind how to split the different cases inside the constructor.

Comment: Now how could I extend it to support the unary operator 'not'? As in this example:
    'false ∨ false ∨ false ∨ (¬ (x0 >= 0.0)) ∨ false'

Comment: Fabian I made an edit at the bottom of the post. Hopefully this shows you how you can customise the behaviour to meet your needs.

Comment: Fabian, in my final section I showed how to break this problem down into more manageable parts. Hopefully it shows you how to make decisions about your data and possible computations you'd like to perform on it.

Comment: Wow, such a great and verbose explanation. Your solution is so nice and elegant. Now the only thing left to do is change the expr() function such that * takes precedence over +.